What backbone to use for Helper dependent adenovirus (HDAd)
I have been trying to design a plasmid for a helper dependent adenovirus but while looking i wasn't able to see a backbone specifically for HDAds so I was wondering if a general adenovirus backbone would work or if there is an available backbone for helper dependent adenoviruses. A helper dependent adenovirus is considered a next generation adenovirus and has advantages like less immune response and longer effect, there are other considerations like attachment sites and wondered if there was already a commercially availible backbone that took the considerations into effect
I plan on making it consumed orally and to express a therapeutic protein

Can you say more about what your application is for the adenovirus? What are you going to do with it?

to add production of a protein by being consumed orally but so far just as a design project

So, I'm not at all sure that this is what you are doing, but your ultimate goal may be to make some sort of vector for therapeutic protein expression. You are interested in using a helper-dependent adenovirus (don't know what that is without any references, but maybe someone does). I think that what you want is to just dump some kind of constitutive expression cassette into that virus backbone, which will turn on full power when it is ingested. It looks like maybe this is a vehicle sometimes for vaccines. Can you look at what people have used in the past? If not, why haven't you?

I am pretty sure it would be considered a vector for therapeutic protein expression, And a helper-dependent adenovirus is also considered a gutless adenovirus or a next generation adenovirus with less immune response and longer expression. The backbone as far as I can tell has some of the same things as an adenovirus but some specific concerns like attachment sites to get into the adenovirus and I was wondering if there was a backbone that had these pre integrated

Having a lot of this detail directly in the question would make it a lot easier to answer. Consider editing the question and providing this and additional information (citations, some maps of some vectors that you are considering, examples). That will likely lead to a more helpful answer than I can give you here.
